# Weekend events from table in between start and end date

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find weekend events from table. Table have from date and to date.

I wrote query for, if from and to dates are equal. i.e,

```
SELECT *
from table
where date_from < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) and
      (DAYOFWEEK(date_from) = 7 or DAYOFWEEK(date_from) = 1)
```

What will be the query for, in between start date and end date happens this Saturday or Sunday?

Eg:

```
Start Date    End Date    Show/Don't Show
29-10-2014    30-10-2014  Don't Show
29-10-2014    03-11-2014  Show
03-11-2014    03-12-2014  Don't Show
29-10-2014    03-12-2014  Show
01-11-2014    01-11-2014  Show
```

Comment: The query is using MySQL syntax so I removed the SQL Server tag.

Comment: This is MySQL? I see no dates :-(

Comment: What do you mean by "this Saturday or Sunday"? Do you mean "the nearest upcoming Saturday and Sunday from now"?

Comment: Yes. The nearest upcoming Saturday and Sunday from now

Comment: I offer a solution according to your comment, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want show the next Saturday and Sunday (First day of week is Monday), you could using `5 - Weekday(curdate())` to calculate the diff days to next Saturday, and `6 - Weekday(curdate())` for next Sunday.

So:

```
SELECT *
from 
    my_table
where 
    DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL (7+5 - weekday(curdate()))%7 DAY) between date_from and date_to
or 
    DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 - weekday(curdate()) DAY) between date_from and date_to
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce837/2)</kbd>

**Explain**

`Weekday` return 0-6 stand for Monday to Sunday

So to get next Sunday(`Weekday(aSunday)=6`) only need to add `6 - weedday(curdate())` days.

To get next Saturday(`Weekday(aSaturday)=5`), need to consider curdate is a Sunday, then add `5 - 6` will get yesterday. So add 7 and mod 7 can get 6, that will get next Saturday form this Sunday.